# Helm: get list of the keys in a map

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I am trying to get the list of all the keys that are defined in my Values.yaml. Right now I have added an extra variable just to hold the keys as a list which is not the best solution. is there a way to get the list of all the keys in a map?

Since I have the same variable defined as a list in another values.yaml as list, I want to flatten the map the first time to get the list so that I can have the same logic on my helm template for looping.

I thought of looping through the map and creating a dynamic list. But seems that it is not possibel as list is immutable.

Values.yaml

```
default:
    environment_names: ## this is what i want to eliminate
    - preview
    - preview-test
    environments: 
      preview: 
        server: https://sds
        something: adkfgdf
      preview-test:  
        server: https://sds
      staging: 
        server: https://35.246.225.83
```

Application.yaml template

```
  {{- range $service := $.Values.services }}
  {{- $environment_names := $.Values.default.environment_names }} ## default value (here i want to write a funtion which would flatten the map and return the keys)
  {{- if $service.environments }} ## if defined in another vaues.yaml as list
     {{- $environment_names:= $service.environments }}
  {{- range $env_name := $environment_names }} ## looping through the environments
  {{- $environment := get $.Values.default.environments $env_name }} ## reading from the map from default
  ---
  apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
  kind: Application
  debug1: {{ $environment_names }}
  debug: {{ $env_name }}
  debug2: {{ $service.name }}
  {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got the list of the keys in the template (I tried using functions which did not work for me, so this coudl be improved)

```html
{{- $env_list:= list }}
{{- range $k,$v:= $.Values.default.environments }}
   {{- $env_list = append $env_list $k }}
{{- end }}
{{- range $service := $.Values.services }}
{{- $environment_names:= ternary $service.environments $env_list (hasKey $service "environments") }}
```

I could replace `$.Values.default.environment_names` with  `env_list` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Helm includes a number of extension functions, and among these is a [`keys`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/) function that does exactly what you ask: given a dict-type object (like `.Values`) it returns its keys as a list.

---

For the overall structure of the Helm template you show, remember that it's possible to construct additional values files and pass them using `helm install -f` and similar options; you don't have to put every possible setting for every possible environment in the single `values.yaml` file.  I might create a separate file per environment:

```yaml
# values-preview.yaml
server: https://sds
something: adkfgdf
```

```yaml
# values-staging.yaml
server: https://35.246.225.83
```

Now if you, for example, `helm install -f values-staging.yaml`, then `.Values.server` will expand to the configured location of the server, without any of the complex conditional logic you show.